# Custom action button rights but for other list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, ribbon

Have list A that is accessible to all participants, and some work flow that produce items on second list B.

All run manually via button on Ribbon on display form on list A.

I would like to disable that button based on user permissions from list B.

Rights mask is just for current list (my list A)?
What other options do I have (any without VS?) ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Action declaration have *EnabledScript* property, where any valid JS function can be placed, it can check any conditions and should return true or false.

So VisualStudion is needed *or* direct access to sharepoint filesystem so one can modify proper ribbon xml declarations.